# How to attach parents' educational attainment to their children in Stata? (Using IPUMS - USA dataset)

Tags: data-transformation, econometrics, stata

I am interested in the relationship between children's success in high school and their mother's educational attainment. For this reason, I would like to create a variable called mom_education, which would be assigned to every member of each household.

I am sure this can be accomplished, but my Stata skills are insufficient.
The variables which I'd like to use are:
**serial** - household serial number
**pernum** - person number in household
**momloc** - mother's location in the household; i.e. if momloc of the 4th member of the household is 2, then the second person (pernum = 2) is the mother of the 4th person (pernum=4). (It is possible that momloc = 0 for all members of the household if none of the members' mom lives in the household.)
**educ** - education attainment

The algorithm I was trying to write was something like: For a given household, if momloc = n for some person in the household, then call person pernum = n in the household "mom".

Then, for the sake of a merge, create a temp.dat dataset which only contains moms. For this dataset, rename educ to mom_education. Then do a one to many merge of the temp.dat dataset and our former dataset, so that every household now contains the variable mom_education.

The biggest problem I am having is with the first part of the algorithm. I would really appreciate your help, thank you.

Comment: Cross-posted at http://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/334426-how-to-attach-parents-educational-attainment-to-their-children-in-stata-using-ipums-usa-dataset See e.g. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141823/why-is-cross-posting-wrong-on-an-external-site? for advice to make cross-posting explicit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sounds very complicated... why not exploit the `serial` variable?

First, combine serial and pernum and create a long ID variable. E.g. serial 1122 and pernum 05 will become 112205.

Then, combine serial and momloc and create another long ID. E.g. serial 1122 and momloc 02 will become 112202.

Now, all the kids will have a serial+momloc that is matchable with the serial+pernum of the mother, you can proceed from there.

Comment: This is a really cool way, I will definitely try it out! I ended up using a code from another site (sorry for cross-listing, I was told later it's not right), and here is the link for anyone else interested: http://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/334426-how-to-attach-parents-educational-attainment-to-their-children-in-stata-using-ipums-usa-dataset .